# the raw command to compile `login`

Tags: login, dpkg, compiling, make, configure

I want to manually compile the login command (with the exact CC and LD commands).

https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/login

```
/tmp/shadow_4.8.1.orig/src$ make VERBOSE=1
  CC       login.o
  CCLD     login
```

The above command doesn't show the exact command. When I run the following, I see the following error.

```
$ gcc -o login login.c
login.c:33:10: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
   33 | #include <config.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Could anybody show me how to get the exact commands used to compile the program login? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, where the build is configured by `automake`, you need `V=1` not `VERBOSE=1`:

```
$ make V=1 login
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../lib -I../libmisc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/share/locale\"   -g -O2 -MT login.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/login.Tpo -c -o login.o login.c
login.c: In function ‘alarm_handler’:
login.c:424:2: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  424 |  write (STDERR_FILENO, tmsg, strlen (tmsg));
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mv -f .deps/login.Tpo .deps/login.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../lib -I../libmisc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/share/locale\"   -g -O2 -MT login_nopam.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/login_nopam.Tpo -c -o login_nopam.o login_nopam.c
login_nopam.c: In function ‘netgroup_match’:
login_nopam.c:198:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘getdomainname’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  198 |   getdomainname (domain, MAXHOSTNAMELEN);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mv -f .deps/login_nopam.Tpo .deps/login_nopam.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o login login.o login_nopam.o  ../libmisc/libmisc.a ../lib/libshadow.la    -lcrypt
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o login login.o login_nopam.o  ../libmisc/libmisc.a ../lib/.libs/libshadow.a -lcrypt
```

To build the whole package, change to the `src` directory's parent directory and run

```
./configure
make
```

See also:

- [How Automake can help in silencing make](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Automake-Silent-Rules.html)

Comment: Where is `V` defined? It depends on login_nopam.o  ../libmisc/libmisc.a ../lib/.libs/libshadow.a, which can depend on other files as well. How to get the complete commands to compile `login` including all the dependencies?

Comment: @user1424739 I have added a link to the automake documentation about the `V` parameter. To build the libraries, run `./configure` and `make` in the parent directory like I already mentioned.

Comment: You misunderstood my second question. I am asking how to get all the raw commands (and only those commands but not any other irrelevant commands) (so that I can manually compile the dependencies) instead of just compiling the dependencies.

Comment: @user1424739 ... so add `V=1` to the `make` command in the parent dir... or in the `lib` dir? You may need to `make clean` or `touch` the relevant source file(s) to force re-compilation if you already built them without `V=1`

Comment: So, there is no automatic way to trace back to all the dependencies and their dependencies? To trace back one more level of dependency, I have to do it manually as you mentioned to remove some intermediate files?

Comment: When I delete `lib/.libs/libshadow.a`, it can not make. How to figure out what commands compiled it?

Comment: @user1424739 same process - go to the containing directory and re-make the target. You can use make's `-n` option to do a "dry run" if you wish.